# A deleted post is it visible to other users?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-posts

When I delete a answer, I can undelete it.

But the other users, the common users, not admin, can they see it?

I have just delete a my answer because it is wrong and am wondering to whom it might still be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted posts are visible to users having 10K+ reputation, as this is accompanied by the [Access to moderator tools privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Specifically, this privilege entitles the user to:

- View deleted posts
- Cast delete and undelete votes on questions
- Access moderator tools
- Edit tags inline

Of course, this is by default available to moderators.

Comment: Ok. I imagine something of this kind, but I wasn't certain.